# Configure Custom TableViewCell Outside of TableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView with a custom cell that requires rather lengthy configuration and is used more than once in my app. I would like to avoid duplicated code and just configure the cell in one place. Can I create a function like this?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "betterPostCell", for: indexPath) as! BetterPostCell

        return configureCell(cell)
}
```

Ideally, I would be able to put `configureCell` in my BetterPostCell class. Is this possible?

Comment: Inside of your `BetterPostCell` class add `configure<T>(withItem item:T)` the you'd call cell.configure(withItem: _item) and return the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, and it's a nice way to keep your table view code from blowing up, especially if you have many different types of cells in one table view.

In your BetterPostCell class, create a method called configure like so:

```
func configure() {
     //configure your cell
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAt method, just call that method from your cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "betterPostCell", for: indexPath) as! BetterPostCell
        cell.configure()
        return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a protocol with a `configure` function and associated type `Cell`. Using protocol extensions, you can add default implementations for different cell types, and additional methods.

```
protocol CellConfigurable {
    associatedType Cell

    func configure(_ cell: Cell)
}

extension CellConfigurable where Cell == SomeTableViewCell {

    func configure(_ cell: SomeTableViewCell) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: where to write this extension

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code to create CustomCell:- 

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.initViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.perform(#selector(self.initViews), with: self, afterDelay: 0)
    }

    //MARK: Init views
    func initViews()   {
        //Add your code 
    }

    //MARK: Layout subviews

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    // Here you can code for layout subviews
    }

    //MARK: Update all valuesw model

    func updateWithModel(_ model: AnyObject) { 
    //here you can update values for cell  
    }

}


//Call CustomCell in Tableview class

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.updateWithModel(items[indexPath.row])
        return cell
}
```